# Optimize OpenGL ES 2.0 drawing iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have this huge model(helix) created with 2 million vertices at once and some million more indices for which vertices to use.

I am pretty sure this is a very bad way to draw so many vertices.

I need some hints to where I should start to optimize this?

I thought about copying 1 round of my helix (vertices) and moving the z of that. But in the end, I would be drawing a lot of triangles at once again...

Comment: There are a lot of possible bottlenecks here. Find out which by profiling with Xcode and Instruments before you start optimizing. Your thought isn't too far off, though — all those triangles might be cheaper if they're in a smaller VBO that's rendered with a single draw call [using instancing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Performance/Performance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH105-SW20). Or they might not — again, it  depends on where your bottleneck is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How naive are you currently being? As per rickster's comment, there's a serious case of potential premature optimisation here: the correct way to optimise is to find the actual bottlenecks and to widen those.

Knee-jerk thoughts:

Minimise memory bandwidth. Pack your vertices into the smallest space they can fit into (i.e. limit precision where it is acceptable to do so) and make sure all the attributes that describe a single vertex are contiguously stored (i.e. the individual arrays themselves will be interleaved).

Consider breaking your model up to achieve that aim. Instanced drawing as rickster suggests is a good idea if it's sufficiently repetitive. You might also consider what you can do with 65536-vertex segments, since that'll cut your index size.

Use triangle strips if it allows you to specify the geometry in substantially fewer indices, even if you have to add degenerate triangles.

Consider where the camera will be. Do you really need that level of detail all the way around? Will the whole thing even ever be on screen? If not then consider level-of-detail solutions and subdivision for culling (both outside the viewport and within via the occlusion query).